# How to associate vscode protocol with Visual Studio Code Insiders build

Tags: visual-studio-code

Protocol activation of Visual Studio Code Insiders build is not working after a fresh install.

- I don't have the release build of VS Code on this machine, just the Insider build.
- Links from Azure DevOps to "Clone in VS Code" do not work because the "vscode:" protocol is not associated with the Insider build.

How do I recreate this missing protocol in the Windows registry? Or better yet, is there a command that I can run to do these edits for me?